# R programming - How to convert model output into data frame

Tags: r, r-caret

below are my scripts in running KNN model using cross validate method.

```
## cross validation

library(caret)
cvroc <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                   number = 10, # number of iteration 
                   repeats = 3,
                   classProbs = TRUE,
                   summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

#KNN Model
set.seed(222)
fit_roc <- train(admit ~. , 
             data = training,
             method = 'knn',
             tuneLength = 20,
             trControl = cvroc, .
             preProc = c("center","scale"), 
             metric = "ROC",
             tuneGrid =expand.grid(k=1:60))
fit_roc
```

[KNN model output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6nYT.png)

Question:
My question will be, how can i convert the output from the model into a data.frame?
i used the command below it gives error.

```
aa <- data.frame(fit_roc)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take a look at `str(fit_roc)`. You'll somewhere find the dataframe. If not, condider to share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Check out `broom` package which is made exactly for this purpose

Comment: Thanks Sergey, will look up broom package.!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which part of the output you want, you can do the following: The point is `fit_roc$whatever you want to extract`

```
fit_roc$results
```

Comment: Thanks, manage to convert the results output into data.frame format.

Comment: Great.Please note that You can accept and/or upvote an answer if you feel it helped